# Proof of a sustitution on the magnitude of the separation vector.

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, substitution

Given the separation vector and its magnitude:

$\displaystyle \vec{r} =( x-x') \ \hat{i} +( y-y') \ \hat{j} +( z-z') \ \hat{k}$

$\displaystyle r=\left[( x-x')^{2} +( y-y')^{2} \ +( z-z')^{2}\right]^{1/2} \ $

and a new substitution being:

$\displaystyle \vec{\alpha} =( x-x')^{2} \ \hat{i} +( y-y')^{2} \ \hat{j} +( z-z')^{2} \ \hat{k}$

I am unable to prove that the following statement is true:

$\displaystyle \alpha ^{3/2} =r^{2}$

Comment: Without any other conditions it is not true. Take $x'=y'=z'=0$ and $x=y=z=1$. Then $\|r\|=\sqrt{3}$ and $\|\alpha\|=\sqrt{3}$ as well. Then $\|\alpha\|^{3/2} \neq \|r\|^2$.

Comment: This is very interesting, you're right. I was trying to analyze the laplacian of 1/r, and the reference i was following uses such substitution. I'll try to derive it without it.
Thanks for the quick response